# How to list organization, project, azure devops team, repo information from DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have several Azure DevOps instances, each with several organizations, each organization with several projects, each project with several teams and repos.

How do i programmatically connect to one instance, and get a listing of all repos, ideally in csv format:

Output such as:
organization   project   team   repo

Many thanks in advance

.GET https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=6.1-preview.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i programmatically connect to one instance, and get a listing of all repos, ideally in csv

You can use the following Rest APIs to get the Organization, Projects, Team, Repo.

Get Organizations: [Accounts - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/account/accounts/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)

Get Projects: [Projects - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)

Get Repos: [Repositories - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)

Get Teams: [Teams - Get All Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/teams/get-all-teams?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP)

We can use PowerShell scripts to run the Rest APIs to get all required information.

Here is the example:

```
$token = "PAT"

$GetProfile="https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/profile/profiles/me?api-version=7.1-preview.3"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetProfile -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

$publicAlias = $response.publicAlias

echo $publicAlias

$GetOrganizations= "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/accounts?memberId=$($publicAlias)&api-version=7.1-preview.1"

$response1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetOrganizations -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

foreach($organizationObj in $response1.value)
{
   $organizationname= $organizationObj.accountName
   $GetProjects ="https://dev.azure.com/$($organizationname)/_apis/projects?api-version=7.1-preview.4" 
   $response2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetProjects -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json
   foreach($projectObj in $response2.value)
   {
      $projectname = $projectObj.name
      $GetRepos ="https://dev.azure.com/$($organizationname)/$($projectname)/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=6.1-preview.1"
      $response3 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetRepos -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json
      foreach($repoObj in $response3.value)
      {
         $reponame = $repoObj.name
         $Output = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        organization = $organizationname
        project =$projectname
        repo = $reponame
       } | Select-Object organization, project,repo
    $Output | Export-Csv C:\repo2.csv -Append

      }
      

   }
   $Getteam="https://dev.azure.com/$($organizationname)/_apis/teams?api-version=6.0-preview.3"
   $response4 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Getteam -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json
   foreach($teamObj in $response4.value)
   {
     $teamname = $teamObj.name
     $teamprojectname =$teamobj.projectName
     $Output = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
      organization = $organizationname
      project =$teamprojectname
      team = $teamname
       } | Select-Object organization, project,team
    $Output | Export-Csv C:\team1.csv -Append
   }

}
```

Since the repos belongs to the entire project rather than a single team, I suggest that you can generate two excels, one to output all repos, and the other to output all teams.

The PowerShell script will generate two excels to output all repos and teams.

**Note:** When you create the PAT to run the Rest APIs, you need to use **All accessible organization PAT**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is great thanks! Another option i found is using the gh cli extension gh-ado2gh inventory--report option

Comment: @MarkS if the answer can give you some help，you may consider accepting it. or you can write a new answer to share your methods and accepting it. this will be helpful to other users who have the same issue.